# Parse a date in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, date-parsing

I have a date (Which is actually parsed from a PDF) and it could be any of the following format:

```
MM/DD/YYYY
MM/DD/YY
M/D/YY
October 15, 2007
Oct 15, 2007
```

Is there any gem or function available in rails or ruby to parse my date? 
Or I need to parse it using regex?

BTW I'm using ruby on rails 3.2.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can try [`Date.parse(date_string)`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse).

You might also use [`Date#strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) if you need a specific format:

```
> Date.strptime("10/15/2013", "%m/%d/%Y")
=> Tue, 15 Oct 2013
```

For a general solution:

```
format_str = "%m/%d/" + (date_str =~ /\d{4}/ ? "%Y" : "%y")
date = Date.parse(date_str) rescue Date.strptime(date_str, format_str)
```

Comment: I can't use strptime as I don't know the format of my date :(

Comment: You could infer it easily enough, no? If it won't parse with `Date.parse`, then split("/").last will be either 2 or 4 characters, letting you know if you should be using %y or %Y.

Comment: So what your method is doing is that If it can't parse american format it will simply give it to strptime.I think it will work let me test it.

Comment: Correct. There are a few ways to do that; mine is sloppy-but-effective. :)

Comment: Most of the time my date will be in american format and if the date is less than 12 Date.parse will parse it considering it as a month.How about Date.strptime(date_str, format_str) rescue Date.parse(date_str) ?

Comment: Worth a shot. Find what works for you - between those two methods, though, you should be able to handle all of those date formats.

Comment: I have tested after reversing(Date.strptime(date_str, format_str) rescue Date.parse(date_str)) and its working great. Most of the dates I have ,It can parse it.And thanks a lot for the help please edit your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 7):

I find the chronic gem very easy to use for time parsing and it should work for you. i tried the examples you gave.

https://github.com/mojombo/chronic

Comment: Seems to be good for handling complex dates, is there any option where I can specify that my dates coming will be in MM/DD/YYYY format and not DD/MM/YYYY format?

Comment: this should be the default, but you can set the endianness like this `endian_precedence: :little` and it will parse DD/MM/YYYY