# changing parameters in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller with the following methods

```
 def create
    @todo = Event.new(event_params)
    ...
 end

 def event_params
   form_params = [:title, :type, :owner_id, :note, :occurred, :due]
   form_params[:due].strftime!("%Y-%m-%d")
   params.permit(form_params)
 end
```

I found that when I post a date (:due or :occurred) to the create method with a format of mm/dd/yyyy instead of dd/mm/yyyy I'm getting an argument out of range for a date such as 10/30/2014.  So I'm trying to convert the date values in the parameters before it calls Event.new

The line - form_params[:due].strftime!("%Y-%m-%d") - is not working and after quite a bit of googling, I can't seem to figure out the right way to modify the value of a parameter.  The error I get currently for that line is "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer".  How can I do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's discuss each line of your code to make it clear where the mistake is.

```
form_params = [:title, :type, :owner_id, :note, :occurred, :due]
```

First, you declare an array of symbols and assign that array to `form_params` variable. It's just a simple plain array, not an associative one, so you can access its values using indexes only, e.g. `form_params[0]` would return `:title`, but `form_params[:due]` is a runtime error as `:due` is not an integer index.
Actually, the purpose of `event_params` method should be as simple as stating which parameters you allow to be mass-assigned to your objects, so it should look like

```
params.permit([:title, :type, :owner_id, :note, :occurred, :due])
```

Getting further, your aim is to edit parameters which came from client-side. As of various dates formats parsing, please refer to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563048/parse-a-date-in-rails).

---

**Disclaimer**: It could be much more elegant to force users to pass `due` date in conventional `%Y-%m-%d` format. Please give a look to [rails dates helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html) methods.

---

That parameters reside in `params` hash, so you could rewrite appropriate key:

```
def event_params
  params["due"] = Date.strptime(params["due"], "%m/%d/%Y").to_s
  # here we've converted date format to standard %Y-%m-%d
  params.permit([:title, :type, :owner_id, :note, :occurred, :due])
end
```

This should do two things:

1. Replace user's `due` with appropriate date format
2. Allow enumerated keys to be mass-assigned for your object

And the rest of your code should work fine with this correction:

```
def create
  @todo = Event.new(event_params)
  ...
```

However, beware of side effects:

1. Using `event_params` restricts you from getting actual `%m/%d/%Y` user input now.
2. Malefactor would be able to pass some unparsable string instead of `%m/%d/%Y` formatted date and it would end in runtime error.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  However when I leave the event_params method to not change the value and instead do it after Event.new as you've shown, I again get the argument out of range error on that line so it never gets to the next line to change the value.  If I do it with strftime in the event_params method, I get the error I mentioned above - undefined method `strftime!' for "10/29/2014":String.  Is there a usual way to have your controller accept dates in a mm/dd/yyyy format without having to jump through these kind of hoops?

Comment: @geoffswartz I edited answer to include reference to [date conversions topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563048/parse-a-date-in-rails), please check it out.

Comment: Thanks again.  Based on the article, it "sounds" like params["due"] = Date.parse(params["due"]) should work.  But I get an invalid date error and I've confirmed I'm passing in a string of "10/30/2014".  Am I misunderstanding how it is to work?  Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: @geoffswartz `Date.parse` accepts date in `%d/%m/%Y` format, but you pass `%m/%d/%Y`. `strptime` should work for this case. I've updated my answer a little bit again, please check code snippets once again.

Comment: When I try params["due"] = Date.strptime(params["due"], "%m/%d/%Y").to_s I don't get an error but then when I logger.info params["due"] it writes out 10/30/2014 to the console instead of 30/10/2014  So it's not actually changing the value of the parameter.

Comment: @geoffswartz does it allow you to create object of `Event` with desired date or not? what database state do you have when your `create` method is done?

Comment: No it won't create the event.  Since it's not converting the date from 10/30/2014 to 30/10/2014 when it gets to the Event.new line it bombs with arguments out of range error.

Comment: Ok, I don't know what happened, but after restarting the rails server now it's working.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning form_params an array of symbols, and you can't reference an element of an array by symbol, thus your error.  You probably want that to look like this:

```
form_params = params.permit(:title, :type, :owner_id, :note, :occurred, :due)
```

which will give you the hash you are looking for.

Edit: at first I didn't check the date manipulation you were attempting.  You would need to use [Date.strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) to convert your string to a date, but you need to know the date format.  Unfortunately, you cannot accurately guess that type of thing.  If you know the date will be mm/dd/yyyy, you could convert formats like this:

```
params[:due] = Date.strptime(params[:due], '%m/%d/%Y').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: ok, thanks, that gets me further.  so on to the next problem.  how do I convert it to proper date format?  when I use what I have above I get this error - undefined method `strftime!' for "10/29/2014":String

Comment: Ahh...strftime is a Date function, not a String function. I edited my answer to show how to do that kind of conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Super late to the game but you may consider using this gem: github.com/launchpadlab/decanter

It allows you to easily define how incoming params should be parsed.

More on it here: https://medium.com/launchpad-lab/the-missing-step-in-rails-controllers-82aaa9172165